# how to convert this IRI to URI?

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

how to convert this IRI to URI ?

http://down.qnwz.cn/uploads/media/broadcast/storymagazine/爱情的底牌.mp3

I hope the result type should be Qurl ,thanks

it seems that

```
QUrl QUrl::fromEncoded ( const QByteArray & input )
```

doesn’t work here .

```
>>> from PyQt4.QtCore import *
>>> url='http://down.qnwz.cn/uploads/media/broadcast/storymagazine/爱情的底牌.mp3'
>>> QUrl.fromEncoded (QUrl(url).toEncoded())
PyQt4.QtCore.QUrl('http://down.qnwz.cn/uploads/media/broadcast/storymagazine/爱情的底牌.mp3')
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to convert non-latin1 characters to percent encoding. Use `QUrl::toEncoded`:

```
 >>> QUrl(url).toEncoded()
```

> PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray('http://down.qnwz.cn/uploads/media/broadcast/storymagazine/%C3%A7%C2%88%C2%B1%C3%A6%C2%83%C2%85%C3%A7%C2%9A%C2%84%C3%A5%C2%BA%C2%95%C3%A7%C2%89%C2%8C.mp3')

You can then convert it back to the QUrl:

```
QUrl(QString.fromUtf8(QUrl(url).toEncoded()))
```